# Generate Monte Carlo simulation of multivariate lognormal or weibull distributions in R

Tags: math, correlation, normal-distribution, montecarlo, weibull

I intend to perform a Monte Carlo simulation of asset returns in R. I am currently using the `rmvnorm` function in the `mvtnorm` R package to generate simulated returns based on multivariate normal distribution, taking into account asset return correlations. Based on historical asset prices, the asset returns (bonds) appear to be more similar to a lognormal or weibull distribution.

Is there any R package that can perform a Monte Carlo simulation under multivariate lognormal and weibull distributions, integrating the asset return correlation matrix?

Alternatively, can the existing multivariate normal distribution packages (`mvtnorm`, `MASS`) be tweaked to account for a multivariate lognormal or weibull distribution?